# How to automate a macOS Finder Extension with AppleScript or Automator?

Tags: finder, applescript, automator

I am trying to improve a photo processing AppleScript I've already written. I have a set of files in a folder I'd like to send to an app, DXO PureRaw. I currently do this in with:

open newFolderPath using application file "DxO PureRAW 3.app" of folder "Applications" of startup disk

It works, but I need to manually start the PureRaw processing. PureRaw itself doesn't seem to be scriptable to trigger the processing once is has the photos.

PureRaw *does* provide a Finder Extension that allows the user to select a single or multiple files in Finder, right-click and select the DXO PureRaw processing mode from a menu.

I'd like to trigger one of these processing modes on the set of files.

Any tips of triggering this menu (including the "to DNG" submenu) from AppleScript or Automator?

[image]

Comment: Go to System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services. Does it have an entry in there? If so, you can just key-command it. Done. [The checkbox is for it to appear in a menu, the key command to directly action it on your current selection] https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPs7v.jpg I don't have DXO but this is something like you might see when you get there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That would be an easy way to do it. But no, the options to start DxO PureRaw do not show up in Keyboard Shortcuts->Services.

Comment: It might be worth checking if they implement it similarly to Graphic Converter [though theirs **do** appear in Service]. The actions themselves are inside the app… from where you can call them with Automator if you need. See - https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsX4P.png

Comment: I appreciate the continued suggestions and didn't think to check the Package. Unfortunately, while there is a "FinderExtentionv3" item, it doesn't lead to Automator actions or anything that appears scriptable. Just a UNIX Executable... perhaps there is a command line interface to it. I'll keep looking.